# UIActivityViewController facebook and twitter share options are not avaialble

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios7.1, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am implementing an iOS 7 app for the Sharing feature I am using `UIActivityViewController` but the "Facebook" and "Twitter" option available only when user have already configured his account in Setting. But in **Safari the fb and twitter option is always available even though the account is not configured in setting**. Is there any one who can provide me the answer for this?

Comment: What do you mean in `Safari`? Well, if the user didn't set an account, it won't be shown.

Comment: In iOS Safari app..They will provide the sharing option even the user haven't  setup his account in setting.